# Plesk file manager error "The requested URL /smb/web/file-manager/dir//httpdocs was not found on this server."

Tags: linux, apache, debian, plesk

Whenever I try to access my plesk filemanager i see the following error:

[image]

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case an upgrade was prohibited because i had installed libapache2-mod-security, which interferes with the custom mod-security setup that plesk uses. I uninstalled mod security and upgraded my plesk install from 12.0.x to 12.5.x and now I don't see the error anymore.

Note: Solution likely to be different for people experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting in plesk error logs file ? Also please try to update your plesk panel to latest stable version.

Comment: Not sure which log file to look in, but neither apache error log or var/log/sw-cp-server/error_log had anything in them :/

Comment: and my plesk installation updates automatically I believe